# XMLHttpRequest: "chrome-extension://" prepended to URL gets error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I send a request in *background.js* with jQuery `ajax` or `XMLHttpRequest`, I got the error:

```
background.js:51 GET chrome-extension://kameliefngmopmegikbnifbclhkihkjm/http%3A%2F%2Fhtcjy.com%2Fmobile%2Fshop%2Fm%2Fg%2Fgoods-1.do%3F net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Why add `extension://kameliefngmopmegikbnifbclhkihkjm/` before my request URL?
What can I do for the error.

Here is my code:

*background.js*

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true},function(tab){
        var method = "get";//details.method;
        var actualUrl = "http%3A%2F%2Fhtcjy.com%2Fmobile%2Fshop%2Fm%2Fg%2Fgoods-1.do%3F"; //details.url;
        sendCrossOrigin(actualUrl, method, function(responseText){
            console.log(responseText);
        })
    });
}, {urls: ["*://*/mock/requestOnServer.do?*"]}, ["blocking"] );

function sendCrossOrigin(url, type, success){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(type, url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // innerText does not let the attacker inject HTML elements.
            //documemt.getElementById("resp").innerText = xhr.responseText;
            //var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            success(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "RAP",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "RAP Chrome Plugin for Cross-domain",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "RAP",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "*://htcjy.com/*",
    "*://*/*",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-2.0.0.min.js", "background.js"] 
  },
  "content_scripts":[{
    "matches":["http://*/*"],
    "js":["jquery-2.0.0.min.js", "content_script.js"]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it.
It is because I post the url like `http%3A%2F%2Fhtcjy.com%2Fmobile%2Fshop%2Fm%2Fg%2Fgoods-1.do%3F`

but I write

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "*://htcjy.com/*",
    "*://*/*",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ]
```

it can not match the url, so I called function `decodeURIComponent` to convert to the url `http://htcjy.com/mobile/shop/m/g/goods-1.do?`

so stupid I am.